# Level Data with JSON

Tags: c#, unity

I am doing level data for a game in Unity with C#

I have it in my game as

```
int[,] data = {
            {0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0}
        };
```

The *1s* draw the shape of the board.

I then have JSON like this:

```
{
    "level_01":
    {
        "tiles" : {
            {0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0}
        },
        "target_score": 1000,

    },
    "level_02":
    {
        "tiles" :
        {
            {0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0}
        },
        "target_score": 1000,
    }
}
```

I am aware that the JSON format is broken but lost on what to do to correct it.

Aside from that bit... how would I go about translating the properly formatted JSON to an int[,] in C#?

Comment: There are two questions here: what is wrong with the formatting of this JSON chunk, and how to parse JSON in Unity. The former is wildly off-topic here, while the latter is almost certainly a duplicate (I recommend MiniJSON).

Comment: http://pro.jsonlint.com/ for testing JSON structure.

Comment: also just googling a bit (which you obviously didn't) here's another JSON library: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON

Comment: I actually did Google but thanks for being a douche :)

Answer (score 2):

In "tiles" value, you should change all the curly braces to brackets. In JSON, curly braces mean an object, while brackets mean arrays.

Also about parsing JSON, once you actually have the content of JSON file (via reading the file for example!), there are lots of pure CS libraries to help you parse it. [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for example.